# flutter how to turn a list of objects into a drop down menu?

Tags: flutter, dart, drop-down-menu

I have a list of Brazilian banks, this list below.

```
List<Banks> banksList = [
    Banks(
            code: 1,
            name: 'Banco do Brasil S.A.'
        ),
        Banks(
            code: 3,
            name: 'Banco da Amazônia S.A.'
        ),
        Banks(
            code: 4,
            name: 'Banco do Nordeste do Brasil S.A.'
        ),
        Banks(
            code: 7,
            name: 'Banco Nacional de Desenvolvimento Econômico e Social BNDES'
        ),
        Banks(
            code: 10,
            name: 'Credicoamo Crédito Rural Cooperativa'
        ),
        Banks(
            code: 11,
            name: 'Credit Suisse Hedging-Griffo Corretora de Valores S.A.'
        ),
        Banks(
            code: 12,
            name: 'Banco Inbursa S.A.'
        ),
        Banks(
            code: 14,
            name: 'Natixis Brasil S.A. Banco Múltiplo'
        ),
        Banks(
            code: 15,
            name: 'UBS Brasil Corretora de Câmbio, Títulos e Valores Mobiliários S.A.'
        ),
        Banks(
            code: 16,
            name: 'Coop de Créd. Mútuo dos Despachantes de Trânsito de SC e Rio Grande do Sul'
        ),
        Banks(
            code: 17,
            name: 'BNY Mellon Banco S.A.'
        ),
        Banks(
            code: 18,
            name: 'Banco Tricury S.A.'
        ),
        Banks(
            code: 21,
            name: 'Banestes S.A. Banco do Estado do Espírito Santo'
        ),
        Banks(
            code: 24,
            name: 'Banco Bandepe S.A.'
        ),
        Banks(
            code: 25,
            name: 'Banco Alfa S.A.'
        ),
        Banks(
            code: 29,
            name: 'Banco Itaú Consignado S.A.'
        ),
        Banks(
            code: 33,
            name: 'Banco Santander Banks(Brasil) S. A.'
        ),
        Banks(
            code: 36,
            name: 'Banco Bradesco BBI S.A.'
        ),
        Banks(
            code: 37,
            name: 'Banco do Estado do Pará S.A.'
        ),
        Banks(
            code: 40,
            name: 'Banco Cargill S.A.'
        ),
        Banks(
            code: 41,
            name: 'Banco do Estado do Rio Grande do Sul S.A.'
        ),
        ]
```

I created this class to make a list of it

```
class Banks {
  final int code;
  final String name;

  Banks({
    required this.code,
    required this.name,
  });
}
```

and I created this drop down menu, passing this list,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:soller_acessoria_new_app_nullsafety/views/informacoes/informacoes_controller.dart';

class DropDown extends GetView<InformacoesController> {
  const DropDown({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton(
      value: controller.valueChosen,
        onChanged: (newValue) {
          controller.valueChosen.value = newValue as int;
        },
        items: controller.banksList.map((e) {
          return DropdownMenuItem(
            value: e.code,
            child: Text(e.name),
          );
        }).toList());
  }
}
```

this is my controller page and my value (obs: i am using getx as state manager)

```
//!DROPDOWN

  //ATRIBUTOS

  RxInt valueChosen = 1.obs;

  //LISTA DROPDOWN
```

however I am not sure how to make the drop down menu appear. From this list I need the name to be shown and when selecting a bank I need to send the code to the API. but with the menu as it is I get this error:

```
Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: 0. 
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value
'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart':
package:flutter/…/material/dropdown.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 882 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                return item.value == value;
              }).length == 1'
```

Comment: what is initial value for `controller.valueChosen`?

Comment: the initial value is 0 my friend

Comment: so set it to `1, 3, 4, 7` etc - i mean valid bank `code` (or leave it to `null` if you dont want to setup any initial dropdown value)

Comment: the same error _AssertionError ('package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart': Failed assertion: line 882 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                return item.value == value;
              }).length == 1': There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: 1. 
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value)

Comment: Can you include `controller` ?

Comment: I will add to the question, a second

Comment: it should be `value: controller.valueChosen.value`

Comment: added my controller, only the variable that is controlling the value

Comment: this as you told me above but it's still wrong

Comment: before `return DropdownButton(` add `print('== ${controller.valueChosen.value} ==');` - what do you see?

Comment: My connection fall i'm sorry. Tomorrow i send the result

Comment: hi firend this is the value. == Selecione == is the same value who i paste in the variable

Comment: `controller.valueChosen.value` is an `int` like `1`, `3`, `4` etc (that is valid bank's code), how come it is "Selecione" ??

Comment: my mistake, i solve the problem tnaks for help